# Why does the Morningstar overview of VMMXX say 81% cash?

Tags: money-market, bond-funds

I was reading about Vanguard's Prime Money Market Fund, VMMXX, whose investments are characterized thusly by Investopedia:

> The holdings include U.S. Treasury bills (T-bills) with a 24.1% portfolio weighting, U.S. government obligations at 11.8%, U.S. commercial paper at 4.2%, certificates of deposit (CDs) at 10.6%, and Yankee/foreign obligations at 47.8%.

So it's largely bonds. That said, I am confused as to why [the Morningstar portfolio summary for VMMXX](http://portfolios.morningstar.com/fund/summary?t=VMMXX&region=usa&culture=en-US) describes it as 16% bonds and 81% cash.

Is it just inaccurate site lacking in details, or am I misunderstanding what it's telling me? I have always used it for a quick glance at what a certain fund's holdings are made of.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Morningstar's [definition](http://portfolio.morningstar.com/instantxray/datadef.html) of cash includes "cash equivalents (fixed-income securities with a maturity of one year or less)". So I'm guessing 81% of its holdings are short-term enough to fall into this category.

Comment: As one would expect for a Money Market fund...